# ie11 fixed header not working allowing scroll over

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, internet-explorer-11

I've got a bit of javascript code where on selecting a menu item a pdf file gets loaded into field id=content.  I've also got a fixed header and footer in place.  The code works fine with Chrome, Safari, Edge, Firefox, & Opera but IE11 ignores the fixed header and footer where I've loaded the pdf (but not to the left where I've got the menu).

Here's the javascript to load the pdf:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<object id='provue_file' data='"+file_name+"#view=FitH' type='application/pdf' width='100%'><p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. <a href='"+file_name+"'>Click here to download the PDF</a>. Or <a href='http://get.adobe.com/reader/' target='_blank'>click here to install Adobe Reader</a>.</p></object>";
```

Here's the header and footer css declarations:

```
div.header, div.footer {
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: blue;
    background-color: honeydew;
    clear: left;
}

.footer {
    border-top:1px solid gray;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
```

And here's the html declaring content:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
</div>
```

Please note, it is fine in IE11 until the javascript is run